# iOS/Obj-C: Two MKMapViews, one MapView's annotations not executing?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two separate mapviews inside of one ViewController. Each mapview shows a different set of annotations - one map shows strangers locations, the other map shows friend locations. When I tap an annotation on the first mapview (mapView), I get a detail view with the correct user data. However, when I tap an annotation on the second map view (friendsMapView), the data is being pulled from the dictionary populating the first mapView. After logging the error, I discovered that didSelectAnnotation for friendsMapView is never executed? How can I fix this?

**Code not being executed (EDIT):**

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {

    if (self.mapView == self.mapView) {
        // Do something specific to self.mapView

        PointAnnotation *selectedPoint = (PointAnnotation *) view.annotation;

        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

        OtherUserViewController *yourViewController = (OtherUserViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OtherUserViewController"];

        NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = self.addressData[selectedPoint.index];
        yourViewController.mapuserData = dictionary;

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];


    } else if (self.mapView == self.friendsMapView) {
        // Do something specific to self.friendsMapView

        PointAnnotation *selectedPoint = (PointAnnotation *) view.annotation;

        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

        OtherUserViewController *yourViewController = (OtherUserViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OtherUserViewController"];

        NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = self.friendData[selectedPoint.index];
        yourViewController.mapuserData = dictionary;

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];

    }



    }
```

Full code: **MapViewController.m**

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{

    if (self.mapView == self.mapView) {

    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 1300, 1300);
    [self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];

    } else if (self.mapView == self.friendsMapView) {

        MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 1300, 1300);
        [self.friendsMapView setRegion:[self.friendsMapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];

    }

}

    - (NSString *)deviceLocation {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"latitude: %f longitude: %f", self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
    }
    - (NSString *)deviceLat {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude];
    }
    - (NSString *)deviceLon {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
    }
    - (NSString *)deviceAlt {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", self.locationManager.location.altitude];
    }

        NSMutableDictionary *viewParams = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        [viewParams setValue:@"u000" forKey:@"view_name"];
        [DIOSView viewGet:viewParams success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

            self.addressData = [responseObject mutableCopy];


            NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);


            int index = 0;   //Index to track the data source index while select the annotation call out view.

            for (NSMutableDictionary *multiplelocations in self.addressData) {

                NSString *location = multiplelocations[@"street_address"];
                NSLog(@"Pull addresses %@", location);
                NSString *userNames = multiplelocations[@"users_name"];
                NSString *userBio = multiplelocations[@"userbio"];


                CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

                [geocoder geocodeAddressString:location
                             completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
                                 if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {
                                     CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                                     MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:topResult];

                                     MKCoordinateRegion region = self.mapView.region;

                                     region.span.longitudeDelta /= 8.0;
                                     region.span.latitudeDelta /= 8.0;


                                     PointAnnotation *point = [[PointAnnotation alloc] init];
                                     point.coordinate = placemark.coordinate;
                                     point.title = userNames;
                                     point.subtitle = userBio;
                                     point.index = index;  // Store index here.

                                     [self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
                                 }
                             }
                 ];
                index = index + 1;
            }

        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }];





        NSMutableDictionary *viewParamsFriend = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        [viewParamsFriend setValue:@"accepted_friends" forKey:@"view_name"];
        [DIOSView viewGet:viewParamsFriend success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

            self.friendData = [responseObject mutableCopy];


            NSLog(@"THIS IS FRIEND DATA %@", self.friendData);

            int index = 0;

            for (NSMutableDictionary *multiplelocationsFriend in self.friendData) {


                NSString *location = multiplelocationsFriend[@"address2"];
                NSString *userNames = multiplelocationsFriend[@"node_title"];
                NSString *userBio = multiplelocationsFriend[@"body"];


                       NSLog(@"LOCATION IS HERE %@", location);



                CLGeocoder *geocoderFriend = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
                [geocoderFriend geocodeAddressString:location
                             completionHandler:^(NSArray* placemarks, NSError* error){
                                 if (placemarks && placemarks.count > 0) {
                                     CLPlacemark *topResult = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                                     MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithPlacemark:topResult];

                                     MKCoordinateRegion region = self.friendsMapView.region;

                                     region.span.longitudeDelta /= 8.0;
                                     region.span.latitudeDelta /= 8.0;



                                     PointAnnotation *point = [[PointAnnotation alloc] init];
                                     point.coordinate = placemark.coordinate;
                                     point.title = userNames;
                                     point.subtitle = userBio;
                                     point.index = index;  // Store index here.

                                     [self.friendsMapView addAnnotation:point];
                                 }
                             }
                 ];
                index = index + 1;
            }

        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }];


    }

    -(MKAnnotationView*)mapView:(MKMapView*)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {

        MKAnnotationView *view = nil;
        if (annotation != self.mapView.userLocation) {

            view = [self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"myAnnotationIdentifier"];
            if (!view) {

                static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";

                MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                                                 reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
                annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
                annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mappaw.png"];
                UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

                annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
                annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
                annotationView.draggable = YES;
                return annotationView;


            }
        }
        return view;
    }


    - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {

            PointAnnotation *selectedPoint = (PointAnnotation *) view.annotation;

            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

            OtherUserViewController *yourViewController = (OtherUserViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OtherUserViewController"];

            NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = self.addressData[selectedPoint.index];
            yourViewController.mapuserData = dictionary;

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];

        }


    -(MKAnnotationView*)friendsMapView:(MKMapView*)friendsMapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
        // If you are showing the users location on the map you don't want to change it
        MKAnnotationView *view2 = nil;
        if (annotation != self.friendsMapView.userLocation) {

            view2 = [self.friendsMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"myFriendAnnotationIdentifier"];
            if (!view2) {

                static NSString *AnnotationIdentifier = @"FriendAnnotationIdentifier";

                MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                                                reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
                annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
                annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mappaw.png"];
                UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

                annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
                annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
                annotationView.draggable = YES;
                return annotationView;


            }
        }
        return view2;
    }

    - (void)friendsMapView:(MKMapView *)friendsMapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view2
    {

        PointAnnotation *selectedPoint = (PointAnnotation *) view2.annotation;

        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

        OtherUserViewController *yourViewController = (OtherUserViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OtherUserViewController"];

        NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = self.friendData[selectedPoint.index];

        yourViewController.mapuserData = dictionary;

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];

        NSLog(@"Selected!");


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't makeup method signatures for the delegate methods.

The following is correct:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
```

The following is some made up method that will never be seen as a delegate method:

```
- (void)friendsMapView:(MKMapView *)friendsMapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
```

Just implement the proper delegate methods. Both map views will use the same delegate methods. You act accordingly by using the `mapView` parameter.

For example, your two `didUpdateUserLocation` delegate methods become one as follows:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 1300, 1300);
    [mapView setRegion:[mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];
}
```

That one delegate method will work for both map views.

If you actually need to do something different depending on which map view it is, you do something like the following:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    if mapView == self.mapView {
        // Do something specific to self.mapView
    } else if mapView == self.friendsMapView {
        // Do something specific to self.friendsMapView
    }
}
```

Comment: So shouldn't I write that if statement inside of didSelectAnnotation? And not didUpdateUserLocation?

Comment: I just used that one delegate as an example to demonstrate your issue and a solution. You need to do this with all of the relevant map view delegate methods you are using for your two map views.

Comment: See edit above in "Code Not Being Executed". I've changed it, and my app still doesn't execute the if statement?

Comment: Your `if/else` checks do not match mine. You are comparing `self.mapView` instead of just `mapView`.

Comment: Noted! And, when I just use 'mapView', I get a warning stating "Local declaration of 'mapView' hides instance variable...

Comment: You can rename either the `mapView` property or the `mapView` parameter to avoid the warning. But that warning shouldn't be new. You should have been getting it long before making the changes I suggested.

Comment: Updated code to your above - when I run, I get an empty dictionary (no data in the detailView lol). That said, my if statement is now executed!! But self.friendData[selectedPoint.index] is now being returned as null...

Comment: That's a whole new issue separate from this one. Close this question, do some debugging on your new issue and if needed, post a new question with relevant details to the new issue.